# jQuery .each() array in .each() array

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

Hear an Object Array

```
 advancedParams = [];
 advancedParams["cost"] = [];
 advancedParams["cost"]["from"] = 10;
 advancedParams["cost"]["to"] = 100;
```

But the .each() do not see second array

```
 $.each(advancedParams, function( idx, obj ) {
     console.log(idx); // shows cost
     console.log(obj ); // shows [from: "10", to: "200"]
     $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
         console.log(key); // nothing
         //each have no iterations, why?
     });
 }
```

Comment: `{cost: [from: "10"], [to: "200"]}` i guess it is invalid.

Comment: Find problem. Array binding by advancedParams = {}, but the second was bind by  advancedParams[param] = [], when type advancedParams[param] = {} it start work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely invalid:

```
{cost: [from: "10"], [to: "200"]}
```

because in an array you can't have values with `:` separated.

Instead of declaring an array `[]` you should assign an object.

```
advancedParams = {};
advancedParams["cost"] = {};
```

check in the demo below.

```js
var advancedParams = {};
advancedParams["cost"] = {};
advancedParams["cost"]["from"] = 10;
advancedParams["cost"]["to"] = 100;

$.each(advancedParams, function(i, obj) {
  console.log(obj); // results in "Object {from: 10, to: 100}"
  $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item); // results in "10, 100"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Update array. Simply I tried to explain more simply.

Comment: Yes. Problem was in advancedParams["cost"] = [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Your object definition it's invalid. Look at the error message below :

[image: invalid object definition]

Store it in an object like this : `var obj  = { from: 10, to:200}`. Or if you want an array of objects, do it like this:  `var arr =[{from:10,to:200},{from:1, to:300}]`.